# Why doesn't Html.LabelFor work in a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I thought I have asked this before, but I am not finding it. I am making partial view for a form so I can use it in multiple places. Here is one short snippet:

```
@model Permits.Domain.Entities.PermitRequest

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobAddress)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

My model looks like:

```
public class PermitRequest
{
    [Description("Job address")]
    public string JobAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Why would my label still be "JobAddress" instead of "Job Address" (with the space)? I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[DisplayName("Job address")]
public string JobAddress { get; set; }
```

or if you prefer:

```
[Display(Name = "Job address")]
public string JobAddress { get; set; }
```

Both set the [`DisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.displayname.aspx) property of the ModelMetadata which is used by the LabelFor helper.